# Grunt connect (grunt-contrib-connect) livereload: Fatal error: Port 8000 is already in use by another process

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-connect

I'm setting `grunt-contrib-watch`, and `grunt-contrib-connect` to live reload, like this:

```
watch: {
  options: {
    livereload: true,
  },
  files: ['src/**/*'],
  tasks: ['serve']
},
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      port: 8000,
      base: './dist',
      hostname: '0.0.0.0',
      protocol: 'http',
      livereload: true,
      open: true,
    }
  }
},
```

But I'm getting this error when connect tries to reload:

> ```
> Running "connect:server" (connect) task
> Fatal error: Port 8000 is already in use by another process.
> ```

I tried a few different ports, but had the same problem.

I don't get how `grunt-contrib-connect` server can have a conflict with it's own port.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the `serve` task was where I was starting the server, so it was trying to start another server every time it reloaded. I switched it to a `dev` task where the site was recompiled, but doesn't start a server.

Comment: Awesome, that's a great first step to debugging. I purposely left it out of code, i sent because I had no idea what it was doing

Comment: Yeah, I should have included my whole file. Just difficult, cause it is pretty huge.

Answer (score 1):

A couple requirements:

Make sure you're not already starting up localhost 8000 somewhere else. If you have two local servers running on the same port it won't work. **(Check your other tabs in terminal)**

Make sure the following is in your html(at the bottom with the other js)

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

and then try something like this:

```
connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
              port: 8000,
              hostname: 'localhost',
              livereload: 35729,
              open:{
                target: "http://localhost:8000"
              }
            }
        }
    },       
    watch: {
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },          
        css: {
            files: ['src/**/*'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            },
        },
        html: {    
            files: ["**/*.html"]
        }                
    },
```

Then you can setup a task if you haven't like so:

```
grunt.registerTask("server", ["connect", "watch"]); // Type grunt server -- Creates a server and checks for any changes in the html/css
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a different case but I had exactly the same error message no matter which port number I set in my gruntfile. Turned out that the problem was due to the fact that I had the port number defined as a string not a number.